# Getting "too few arguments in function call" error in SDL_CreateWindow() function

Tags: c++, sdl, sdl-2

```
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>

using namespace std;

const int sWidth = 800, sHeight = 800;

int main() {
    SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVERYTHING);
    SDL_Window *window  = SDL_CreateWindow("My SDL", SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, sWidth, sHeight, SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);

}
```

Comment: The documentation provides [example code](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow#code_examples) that shows the correct usage.  Specifically, you need to specify `SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED` for both `x` *and* `y` coords.

Answer (score 1):

[Documentation](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow) states that SDL_CreateWindow requires six parameters, but you have only provided five. Compiler is telling you the same thing.

Try this

```
SDL_Window *window = SDL_CreateWindow("My SDL", 
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
    SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, 
    sWidth, sHeight, SDL_WINDOW_ALLOW_HIGHDPI);
```

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the [documentation page](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_CreateWindow), `SDL_CreateWindow()` has the following signature:

```cpp
SDL_Window * SDL_CreateWindow(const char *title,
                              int x, int y, int w,
                              int h, Uint32 flags);
```

As you can see, you're missing `int y` window position argument.

Since you're starting learning it, I suggest you to go check some [tutorials](https://wiki.libsdl.org/Tutorials). Lazy foo has some pretty useful ones: https://lazyfoo.net/tutorials/SDL/.